# New divs with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a problem with my JavaScript code. In practice I have a function that starts with the click of a `div`, through ajax and then I query the database and dynamically add the `div` elements with `append()` to the main `div` without reloading the page. Now, I want the JavaScript code to read me also the new `div` elements added by ajax, how can I do without reloading the page?

```
  $(".cc > div").on('dbltap', function(){
  var taskid = $(this).data('id');
  var type = $(this).data('status');
  var device = $(this).data('device');

  if(type == 0){
    var status = "done";
    $(this).data('status', 1);
  }
  else{
    var status = "undone";
    $(this).data('status', 0);
  }

  done_undone(taskid, status, device);
})
```

Comment: Anything you have tried ?

Comment: I added my JavaScript code to the description

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding html content dynamically to the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788783/adding-html-content-dynamically-to-the-page)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to delegate:

```
$(".cc").on("dbltap", "[data-id]", function(){
  // ...
})
```

See more in jQuery docs: https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events